# GXT how to load data with RPC?

Tags: gxt

I' new to GXT and RCP and  need to use both in my project. I want to use
[example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3apaginggrid). Everything works fine, but there is no data. What should I do to load data to grid? For now it could be static data. How to implement service and bind it? Could anyone show me a nice tutorial or explain with simple words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues the best way to start with is to look into the examples sencha provides. For examle the basic grid:
[http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3abasicgrid)

Here the data is provided in a static way (only client side). You have to enhance this with your new knowlege about RPC. To get this knowlege you can read here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Comment: Yep, I already found the solution. It wasn't so complicated at the end. Thanks a lot!